# Middle-Mouse-button overflow bug in Chrome (Win)

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

Observe this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/pixelfreak/AN5Wb/

Everything is fine until you try to scroll by clicking the middle mouse button. Then you can actually view past the boundaries of the element.

This is not happening in FF or IE. Is this a known Chrome bug?

Comment: 15.0.784 beta channel isn't exhibiting this behavior.

Comment: I don't see it in Chomre 16 dev. I believe it was a bug in chrome that has now been fixed (i had seen this behaviour as well)

Comment: Interesting, I'm running the latest stable and I get the bug. I've also noticed that it stretches the wrapper to full size of the window, in my case it was 1664px, which could explain while its moving around the wrapped wrapper.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe this is a Webkit bug. Here's the bug report from Chromium: https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=89366

They say that its fixed in beta versions.